# Sails.js production database migrations, multiple databases

Tags: migration, sails.js, database-migration

I've got to the point in development where I need to set up a database migration tool. So far I've checked out some stackoverflow answers about the subject and it would seem like [sails-db-migrate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-db-migrate) would be good to use, since db-migrate which it's based on seems to have ok docs, and it was recommended by one of the Balderdash guys.

My problem here is this: I have two databases related to my app, one where we store data like users, models related to our devices etc, and one where we store data collected by these devices, like movement data or power on times. I've been able to set it up in Sails pretty easily in connections.js, but I found no mention of using multiple DBs in sails-db-migrate nor db-migrate docs.

Does anyone have experience in how to deal with this situation?